# JavaScript Form validation + Get form values based on input names with no IDs

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to do a form validation but it doesn't seem to be working, theres no IDs on my elements, therefore I'm grabbing them through getElementsByName & getElementsByClass function (written by [Robert Nyman](http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/))

My JS:

```
        window.onload = function() {    
        var feedbackForm = getElementsByClassName("formBuilder"),
            feedbackName = document.getElementsByName("form-name")[0],
            feedbackLocation = document.getElementsByName("form-location")[0],
            feedbackEmail = document.getElementsByName("form-email")[0],
            feedbackComment = document.getElementsByName("form-comment")[0];

        feedbackForm.onsubmit = function () {

            var errors, errorDiv, errorUL = [];

            // check all the fields
            if (!feedbackName.value.match(/\b\w+\b/)) { errors.push("Please enter your full name"); }
            if (!feedbackLocation.value.match(/\b\w+\b/)) { errors.push("Please enter your location"); }
            if (!feedbackEmail.value.match(/^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[\-._+&])*[0-9a-zA-Z_]+@([\-0-9a-zA-Z]+[.])+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/)) { errors.push("Please enter a correct email address"); }
            if (!feedbackComment.value.match(/\b\w+\b/)) { errors.push("Please make a comment"); }

            // if there are errors, display them and cancel submit
            if (errors.length) {
                errorDiv = document.querySelector('#feedback-errors') || appendDiv(feedbackForm, {id: 'feedback-errors', innerHTML: '<ul></ul>'});
                errorUL = errorDiv.querySelector('ul');
                errorUL.innerHTML = errors.map(function (v) {
                    return "<li>#{v}</li>";
                }).join('');
                return false;
            }
            // submit the form
            return true;    
        };          
    }
```

Here is my fiddle show my mark-up & js: http://jsfiddle.net/calebo/rBnwh/

Any suggestions on how to better write the js is welcomed as well.

ps: no jQuery allowed.

Comment: A little bit off-topic; is there no chance for you to use a library like jQuery? That would make this problem a lot more easy :)

Comment: Unfortunately no, would have been able to do it with jQuery validation plugin.

Comment: http://jshint.com/ -> 'getElementsByClassName' is not defined, 'appendDiv' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The methods `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByName` returns an array of elements and hence you should use an index to use a particular element.

Comment: Okay I updated my js in reference to getElementsbyName, however getelementsByClassName shouldn't need an index according to the custom written function?

Comment: The page in the link as indicated by you declares: "Utilizes native getElementsByClassName and XPath support, with a fallback to regular looping. Returns a real array instead of a node list." So it is a real array and accessing from array will need indexing.